# Connecting to a database via JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

When I run the following code, it does not throw any Exception even though I did not provide any specific database URL.

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql:";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root");
```

As per the OCP reviewer book by Boyarsky and Selikoff, the only required part of a JDBC URL format is the protocol (jdbc) and product/vendor (mysql). Given above code, what does it do? Where do this connect?

Comment: default value will take effect, localhost:3306. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection_ConnectionString.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MySQL , if the host and ports are not mentioned, the default values are taken.

Please check this link.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

As per the link ,

> host:port is the host name and port number of the computer hosting
>   your database. If not specified, the default values of host and port
>   are 127.0.0.1 and 3306, respectively.